# Hiding links from Google?

Tags: html

Say I don't want Google to follow my links, or even notice them as links, will simply replacing the a href with an onclick location suffice?

Does Google still treat onclick location as a link? Or do they ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rel="nofollow"` will do it. Google treats that right and won´t follow the link. But noticing isn´t suppressed with that solution. Perhaps don´t post it as a link... even JS will do a good job I think.

Comment: I have over 30,000 pop ups with a jquery lightbox, all being linked to on different pages, but each popup is a disclaimer, shows the same thing... Google are counting it as 30,000 duplicate pages, so I basically want to hide it from them so they don't even notice them as links / content, will a simple nofollow attribute stop this?

Comment: Yes and you should add a meta tag (if possible) to the disclaimer page: nofollow and noindex, then google will ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

`rel="nofollow"` will prevent google from using it in their pagerank algorithm, but won't prevent them from following the link. To prevent them from accessing content on your site you should use robots.txt.

Comment: Say my page is www.site.com/page.html, what would my robots.txt look like to block search engines from this page.html page?

Comment: Would look like:  User-agent: * Disallow: /page.html - but with line break, see: http://webdesign.about.com/od/promotion/ht/htrobotstxt.htm